# @Html.ValidationMessageFor not working in view page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-5

I'm working on update the styling from bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 5, the problem is in bootstrap 3 version when I click "save" button without fill any text box, the page will show validation message like below:

[bootstrap3 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNSTT.jpg)

But when I changed my styling to bootstrap 5, the validation message are not showing anymore:

[bootstrap5 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCUBQ.jpg)

My bootstrap 5 version code are below:

<head>:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Resources from https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">-->  
</head>
```

<body>:

```
<div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Software, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4 required " })
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Software, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "max-width:100%" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Software, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        <p id="errorSoftware" hidden=hidden class=text-danger></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/myJavaScript.js"></script>  
}
```

After test and debug I think the problem are NOT at list below:

1. _Layout.cshtml. I do changed some reference code in Layout page, but another "ADD BUILDING" view page is works fine, they are using the same _Layout view.

   [Add Building page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xqHa.jpg)
2. JavaScript functions and reference link. I tried to delete all my JavaScript function and reference like in 'ADD HARDWARE' view page, but it still not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try as below link. might be jQuery version issue.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dea2ebd7-1ff3-4392-895c-78cf6aed4268/mvc-3-razor-htmlvalidationmessagefor-not-working?forum=aspmvc

Comment: Thank you, but it can not fix my issue.